# Get individual input values from dynamic input fields

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

After creating dynamic inputs along with its dynamic id's by append, only the latest generated input field gives values

Other dynamic input fields return empty string

Note: I'm able to get all values of dynamic inputs by using for loop and pushing inside an array, but i also want to get each input individually on key up . But only final input field created gives value

Here is my fiddle,

https://jsfiddle.net/xd8nvktf/3/

Not able to come up with a solution, Help is appreciated

--Thanks

HTML

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

<button type = "button" class = "btn btn-primary" id = "addInput">Add Input Fields</button>

<div id = "inputAdder">

</div>



</body>
```

JS/JQUERY

```
var a = 0;
var fieldValue;

var dataStored = [];
var valueStored = [];

$("#addInput").on("click", function() {

  a += 1;

  fieldValue = `#filter-value${a}`;

  $("#inputAdder").append(

    `<div class = "row" id="appender${a}">
            
<div class="col-md-4 padderSpace">
                <input id="filter-value${a}">
            </div>
            
</div>`
  )
 
   dataStored.push({value:fieldValue});
   console.log(dataStored) 

})


$("#inputAdder").on("keyup",fieldValue,changeFunc);

   
  function changeFunc(){

console.log($(fieldValue).val()); 

valueStored = [];
  
  for(let i = 0;i<=dataStored.length;i++){

valueStored.push({value:$(dataStored[i].value).val()}) 

console.log(valueStored)
  
  }
  
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass current `textbox` id to your `changeFunc` function.

```
function changeFunc(e){
    console.log($("#" + e.target.id).val()); 
  }
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/1oe4Lupn/) is working sample.

Comment: I understand but I want only one value of input field being altered. (eg:{value:"aa"} and not [{value:"ss"},{value:"aa"},{value:"bb"}].  I want only the current value of input field being typed

Comment: Sorry I didn't catch you by `one value of input field being altered`

Comment: Or lets say I have 4 inputs, can I get the id of the input field I am typing(ex:input 2)?   As I have to write a condition based on the id of a single particular field which is currently being typed

Comment: Yes I've got it and updated my answer. Pleas check